# SQL Server audit per day

Tags: sql-server-2012, audit

I need, for regulation reasons, to create a SQL Server audit files to monitor database actions.
I want to somehow create a file per day so I can ship the file to Azure storage.
I know the audit files are configurable per size only.
Any script\ideas will be much appreciated.
It should be something scheduled once a day that I can run to create a daily file.

Thanks!

Comment: "*to monitor database actions*" - What kind of database actions?...details please.

Comment: Every DML action, every permissions change, new objects etc

Comment: So you want every DML change (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE`, etc), every security change, and assumptively every DDL change (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, etc)? This is going to require more than just Auditing. What retention period do you need for these changes as well?

Comment: I prefer to create a job that will log all changes once a day to a file so I can store it on some blob storage. Later I will load it to a different system like ELK for review or just download the file for the day I need if I have something to investigate

Comment: For the DML actions, do you want to know the actual data that was changed or just knowing *an update* or *an insert* occurred against `TableXYZ` is enough? Do you want to know *who* made the change?

Comment: I would like to know the actual command that ran and by whom